# Create data frames based on duplicate rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `pandas` data frame like below.

```
name    type    loc
abc     cew     hyd
abc     cew     mum
bcd     tes     kkr
ced     fge     abe
ced     fge     abe
```

Now I want to create two data frames first drop all duplicates and then create `data frames`

`1st` `df` (`contains rows for columns where name and type are same`)

```
name    type    loc
abc     cew     hyd
abc     cew     mum
```

`2nd` `df` (`contains rows for columns where name and type are different`)

```
name    type    loc
bcd     tes     kkr
ced     fge     abe
```

I am able to drop the `duplicates` like below

```
df = df1.drop_duplicates(subset='name', keep='first')
```

But from here I have not able to proceed further. Answers with explanation will be helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) by all columns and then use [`duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) for boolean mask with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) for filtering, `~` is for invert mask:

```
df = df.drop_duplicates()
m = df.duplicated(['name','type'], keep=False) 
print (m)
0     True
1     True
2    False
3    False
dtype: bool

df1 = df[m]
print (df1)
  name type  loc
0  abc  cew  hyd
1  abc  cew  mum

df2 = df[~m]
print (df2)
  name type  loc
2  bcd  tes  kkr
3  ced  fge  abe
```

Comment: In your answer in `df1` If I drop duplicate row then the `3and 4` records only one will be left. then that record should be moved to `df2`

Comment: I am getting the below error `Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match`

Comment: You are rigth, sorry. Please check last edit. Need first drop duplicates to new dataframe and then create mask and filter.